# Visual Studio tooltip visualized activation difficult to click

Tags: visualizer

I'm having difficulty positioning the mouse cursor just right over an object name that can be visualized. Is there an alternate or easier way to invoke a visualized other than precise mousing?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Visualizers are addons you get for Visual Studio that give you views of things like datasets. You hover your house over the object, a tiny tooltop appears, then you have to wiggle the mouse over just right to click the visualizer. Then it pops.

Comment: So you're having trouble hovering over identifiers.  Use the Watch window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble hovering over an identifier in your code, you can use the Watch, Autos, and Locals windows instead.

If you're having trouble navigating the tree, you can use the arrow keys.